# Scalable way to check who's viewed a post?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema

I'm building an app that needs to check who, out of millions of users, has not received a post. If a post hasn't been seen by many people, this task will be easy. But if a post has been seen by nearly everyone, it will be difficult to find the needle (the user who hasn't seen it) in the haystack (users who have seen it)

Are there any known strategies to resolving this problem?

Comment: I would split a task into two stages: while the total_views less than total_users/2 I fill a dedicated table with all visitors. at the middle the logic is changed: another table is filled with ids of users who did not visited a post yet, and then a users get removed from this table upon viewing a post.

Comment: Hmm that idea has my gears turning a bit! So this second table, the one that tracks user's who have not seen a post, would it have one row per user? Or store these users in an array or something in one cell?

Comment: it depends. if you could make a binary search of an int of suitable size over  the blob then, perhaps, the update of a blob would be faster than update of the table. you need to experiment with that.

Comment: Also, it depends on the possible size of a blob. for example, if there are couple of millions users and user id is int4, then you would have a blob of ~4M in size at the time of it's creation

Comment: as far as I remember, the postgresql is extensible with custom modules written in arbitrary language and if I am not mistaken, the calls to these extensions could be protected with transaction mechanism. If this is correct, then you could protect blob modification with standard transaction mechanisms

Comment: Thank you @Serge this is a lot of great material. I am not knowledgeable in blobs so I will have to go do some research and learn more. I appreciate the help!